# PHP Include class by using "use" with PSR-4

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I'm using PSR-4, I defined the psr-4 section on composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap":[                
        ],          
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"         
        }
},
```

When I tried to import a class by using "use" keyword

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

I get this error:
FatalErrorException in UploadFilesController.php line 13:
Class 'Controllers\Controller' not found

If I set the static route to the file

```
include("C:\xampp\...");
```

it works, but after that found the same problem with other files including PHP clases like Illuminate.

What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark Baker. Related to your answer, Is It necessary to add an include line by every "use" I made? Why is this problem present in the Illuminate class too?

Comment: Did you dump the autoload? What is the path to `App\Http\Controller\Controller`?

Comment: Yes, I did. The path is C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php

Comment: No, the path is `App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`